# How do I add some DOM elements just after <body> tag from a Chrome Extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I want to insert some DOM nodes to a webpage before it's rendered. I don't have control of the page so I can only create a chrome extension to do so. For instance, I want to insert a `<p>hello world</p>` just after the `<body>` tag. So far as I know I can only insert `<script>` before the `<body>`, in the `<head>`. However, when I try to access `<body>` from that script, it's not working.

What can I do to achieve this?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Test Page</title>
    <style>
        
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var a = document.querySelector('body');
      alert(a) // null
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var a = document.querySelector('body');
      alert(a) // [object HTMLBodyElement]
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Use MutationObserver.

Answer (score -1):

There seems to be an issue with the permissions you use in your chrome extension. In order to access the current page, you need the `activeTab` permission and also, you need to check whether you have allowed the current URL in the extension's manifest.json file. Check the example file below:

```
{
  "name": "Your chrome extension",
  "description": "You can add anything to the body",
  "version": "1.0",
  "permissions": [
    "activeTab"
  ],
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["http://*/*"],
      "js": ["content-script.js"]
    }
  ],
  "browser_action": {
    "default_title": "Append Test Text"
  },
  "manifest_version": 2
}
```

Then, your content-script.js file  should look like the below:

```
var p = document.createElement("p"); 
p.innerHTML = "Hello World";
document.body.insertBefore(p);
```

You can find more information about Chrome extensions by the official docs: [Click Here](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/getstarted)